# Как добавить python программу как значок в панель задач?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу сделать менеджер буфера обмена, но я не знаю как при закрытии программы она появлялась в панели задач как антивирус и т.д. Есть варианты как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Это не панель задач а трей

Answer (score 1):

Делал подобную штуку для PyQt. Посмотрите может Вам подойдет.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QLabel,
    QGridLayout,
    QWidget,
    QCheckBox,
    QSystemTrayIcon,
    QSpacerItem,
    QSizePolicy,
    QMenu,
    QAction,
    QStyle,
    qApp,
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    check_box = None
    tray_icon = None

    # Переопределяем конструктор класса
    def __init__(self):
        # Обязательно нужно вызвать метод супер класса
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))  # Устанавливаем размеры
        self.setWindowTitle(
            "System Tray Application")  # Устанавливаем заголовок окна
        central_widget = QWidget(self)  # Создаём центральный виджет
        self.setCentralWidget(
            central_widget)  # Устанавливаем центральный виджет

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)  # Создаём QGridLayout
        central_widget.setLayout(
            grid_layout
        )  # Устанавливаем данное размещение в центральный виджет
        grid_layout.addWidget(
            QLabel("Application, which can minimize to Tray", self), 0, 0)

        # Добавляем чекбокс, от которого будет зависеть поведение программы при закрытии окна
        self.check_box = QCheckBox("Minimize to Tray")
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.check_box, 1, 0)
        grid_layout.addItem(
            QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding), 2,
            0)

        # Инициализируем QSystemTrayIcon
        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(
            QStyle.SP_ComputerIcon))
        """
            Объявим и добавим действия для работы с иконкой системного трея
            show - показать окно
            hide - скрыть окно
            exit - выход из программы
        """
        show_action = QAction("Show", self)
        quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        hide_action = QAction("Hide", self)
        show_action.triggered.connect(self.show)
        hide_action.triggered.connect(self.hide)
        quit_action.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        tray_menu = QMenu()
        tray_menu.addAction(show_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(hide_action)
        tray_menu.addAction(quit_action)
        self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(tray_menu)
        self.tray_icon.show()

    # Переопределение метода closeEvent, для перехвата события закрытия окна
    # Окно будет закрываться только в том случае, если нет галочки в чекбоксе
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.check_box.isChecked():
            event.ignore()
            self.hide()
            self.tray_icon.showMessage(
                "Tray Program",
                "Application was minimized to Tray",
                QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
                2000,
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Пример взят [отсюда](https://evileg.com/ru/post/68/)